# Is there a preprocessor way to remove a code section from the debug symbols?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang++

I generate C++ code from a script file and I'm using `#line` to ensure I can debug inside my original source code (the same way flex/bison does). But I have some internal calls inside this code, and I don't want the debugger to enter these as they are complicated and purely internal cooking stuff. Is there a way to remove some code from the debug symbol generation ?

Answer (score 0):

No, such a thing does not exist.

Comment: Jesus, the number of ways I had to try rephrasing this to get it past SO's filters 